# Master slave replication jdbc url

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, replication

We have a MySQL setup with one master and two slaves we use Spring 3.0 to connect to the DBs and mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar.
We also use commons dbcp 1.4 for connection pooling.

We use the following jdbc url string:

> jdbc:mysql:replication://[master_ip]:23306,[slave1_ip]:23306,[slave2_ip]:23306/wm_admin?autoReconnectForPools=true&roundRobinLoadBalance=true&loadBalanceBlacklistTimeout=5000&loadBalanceStrategy=random

The problem is that the application will not start if one of the slaves is down, or would halt if it's running and one of the slaves is down. Is there a problem with the url string, should it be setup differently ?

Comment: Why don't you just setup the replication at the server level and then create separate connections for slave and master databases?

Comment: why would I want to do that ?

Comment: Then you can use a normal jdbc connection with a 1 or 2 second timeout and round robin in your app to avoid this issue.  You may also be interested in: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39611

Answer (score 3):

I noticed a similar problem when all slaves were dead. It may be solved with mysql-connector-5.1.38

And next parameters in url:
jdbc:mysql:replication://[master_ip]:23306,[slave1_ip]:23306,[slave2_ip]:23306?connectTimeout=5000&socketTimeout=5000&retriesAllDown=3&allowMasterDownConnections=true&allowSlaveDownConnections=true&loadBalanceBlacklistTimeout=10000&readFromMasterWhenNoSlaves=true

Also, if you don't afraid readonly queries on master - you can add master to slaves list: jdbc:mysql:replication://[master_ip]:23306,[master_ip]:23306,[slave1_ip]:23306,[slave2_ip]:23306

So you won't meet case with "all slaves dead".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a solution from the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-master-slave-replication-connection.html) :

> if you want to allow connection to a master when no slaves are
>   available, set the property readFromMasterWhenNoSlaves to “true.”